# Scipy Optimize (curve_fit) very different results from Excel

Tags: excel, scipy, curve-fitting

Dataset (rockfall) described by power law y=aV^-b.

The fit is just quite off of excel, especially with a very large value on the extreme end. The curve_fit doesn't seem to do well with the largest values. I'm wondering if curve_fit is not the best tool for this purpose? Should I be using a regression of some kind to fit the power law. Thanks for any help I hope the question is clear. Main question: why does it not seem to fit the data very well. The R2 value is pretty good, but the curve fit doesn't 'look' right.

This is the code:

```
x2 = Volume
y2 = cumulative_frequency

def rockfall(x,a1,b1):
    return a1*x**-b1

V = x2.values
quant = y2.values
c, cov = curve_fit(rockfall,V,quant)
print(c)

n = len(x2)
q = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    q[i] = rockfall(x2[i],c[0],c[1])
    
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print('R^2: ',r2_score(quant,q))
print('Samples:',x2.size)
R2=r2_score(quant,q)
```

The data

```
x2  y2
71197   1
12594   2
4780    3
4578    4
3590    5
2624    6
1699    7
1025    8
832.9   9
654.74  10
572.55  11
486.24  12
391.46  13
369.44  14
361 15
356.1   16
314.91  17
300 18
294.7   19
282.45  20
280.7   21
276.6   22
273 23
258.96  24
244.78  25
223 26
190 27
189.7   28
177.04  29
176.16  30
175.8   31
170.03  32
168.23  33
152.8   34
141.6   35
119.75  36
102.76  37
95.27   38
90.16   39
77.82   40
68.58   41
59.92   42
58.25   43
49.44   44
49.05   45
42.9    46
42.25   47
39.55   48
37.78   49
36.31   50
30.84   51
24.73   52
23.2    53
20.64   54
18.67   55
17.63   56
11.13   57
```

I tried cutting off the lowest values (beneath 100). I'm guessing the algorithm of curve_fit is simply different from what I am looking for.

Comment: It's an odd choice to talk about a comparison with an Excel fit, and about "not *seem* to do well [...]", without showing the actual resulting fits (for both Excel and curve_fit). Or at least mention the fitted parameters that Excel has found.

Comment: Note that the fit will be heavily skewed to the data points with low x value, since there are a lot of those. The data points with high x value may stand out to the human eye, but these will contribute little to the overall chi^2 and thus relatively little to the fit.

Comment: "Dataset (rockfall) described by power law ": but if you plot your data in a log-log plot, you'll immediately see they don't lie on a straight line, and thus the model can't fit the data properly.

Comment: Thanks for feedback is very helpful (apologies for not adding the aforementioned results I'd mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of fit model is not a good one, so no fit method - Excel or otherwise - is going to produce sensible results:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

content = '''
x2      ,y2
71197   ,1
12594   ,2
4780    ,3
4578    ,4
3590    ,5
2624    ,6
1699    ,7
1025    ,8
832.9   ,9
654.74  ,10
572.55  ,11
486.24  ,12
391.46  ,13
369.44  ,14
361     ,15
356.1   ,16
314.91  ,17
300     ,18
294.7   ,19
282.45  ,20
280.7   ,21
276.6   ,22
273     ,23
258.96  ,24
244.78  ,25
223     ,26
190     ,27
189.7   ,28
177.04  ,29
176.16  ,30
175.8   ,31
170.03  ,32
168.23  ,33
152.8   ,34
141.6   ,35
119.75  ,36
102.76  ,37
95.27   ,38
90.16   ,39
77.82   ,40
68.58   ,41
59.92   ,42
58.25   ,43
49.44   ,44
49.05   ,45
42.9    ,46
42.25   ,47
39.55   ,48
37.78   ,49
36.31   ,50
30.84   ,51
24.73   ,52
23.2    ,53
20.64   ,54
18.67   ,55
17.63   ,56
11.13   ,57
'''

def rockfall(x: np.ndarray, a1: float, b1: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a1 * x**-b1

with StringIO(content) as f:
    V, quant = np.loadtxt(f,  delimiter=',', skiprows=2).T
print('Samples:', len(V))

c, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(rockfall, V, quant)
print('Parameters:', c)

q = rockfall(V, *c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogx(V, q)
ax.scatter(V, quant)
ax.set_xlabel('Volume')
ax.set_ylabel('Cumulative frequency')
plt.show()
```

```
Samples: 57
Parameters: [166.70100238   0.35558385]
```

[image: fit]

Exponential decay is a better fit:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

content = '''
x2      ,y2
71197   ,1
12594   ,2
4780    ,3
4578    ,4
3590    ,5
2624    ,6
1699    ,7
1025    ,8
832.9   ,9
654.74  ,10
572.55  ,11
486.24  ,12
391.46  ,13
369.44  ,14
361     ,15
356.1   ,16
314.91  ,17
300     ,18
294.7   ,19
282.45  ,20
280.7   ,21
276.6   ,22
273     ,23
258.96  ,24
244.78  ,25
223     ,26
190     ,27
189.7   ,28
177.04  ,29
176.16  ,30
175.8   ,31
170.03  ,32
168.23  ,33
152.8   ,34
141.6   ,35
119.75  ,36
102.76  ,37
95.27   ,38
90.16   ,39
77.82   ,40
68.58   ,41
59.92   ,42
58.25   ,43
49.44   ,44
49.05   ,45
42.9    ,46
42.25   ,47
39.55   ,48
37.78   ,49
36.31   ,50
30.84   ,51
24.73   ,52
23.2    ,53
20.64   ,54
18.67   ,55
17.63   ,56
11.13   ,57
'''

def rockfall(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*np.exp(x*b + c*x**0.5 + d)

with StringIO(content) as f:
    V, quant = np.loadtxt(f,  delimiter=',', skiprows=2).T
print('Samples:', len(V))

c, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    rockfall, V, quant,
    p0=(1, -1e-3, -1e-2, 4),
    maxfev=10_000,
)
print('Parameters:', c)

q = rockfall(V, *c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogx(V, q)
ax.scatter(V, quant)
ax.set_xlabel('Volume')
ax.set_ylabel('Cumulative frequency')
plt.show()
```

```
Samples: 57
Parameters: [ 1.15518142e+00 -8.02092628e-04 -5.76378998e-02  4.12246633e+00]
```

[image: decay]